# Scheduling docker container vs persistent container with scheduled tasks within it

Tags: python, docker, cron, scheduled-tasks, systemd

I have a docker file which runs a python script which should periodically (every 20 minutes) download a json file with an api call.

As far as I can see I can choose between two options to schedule this job:

1. Within Python using e.g. [apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [shed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) or [schedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/)
2. Schedule the docker file using **cron** or **systemd timers**

**Questions:**

- Have I missed any options?
- In general, under what conditions would one chose one over the other?
- Am I correct in assuming option 2. is preferable for my particular case?

Comment: did you get to answers to your questions above?

Comment: I am still not entirely sure which is better but I ended up using the scheduler within Python and it works fine.

Comment: thank you for sharing. so sounds like you have the container running forever and then use one of the python scheduler within the container? right? and which container did you choose?

Comment: I just have a docker container running forever, and a task scheduled with I think apscheduler or shed but I'm not 100% sure which one I chose, I haven't looked at the code in a year xD

Comment: got it. might make sense for me too. that way do not have to mess with cron and paths etc. and can put multiple scripts in that if there are other scripts that I would like to run periodically. thanks!